# VirtualBox virtual networking (MacOSX host, Ubuntu 11.04 guest)

Tags: virtualbox, macosx

I would like my Ubuntu guest to have 2 interfaces:

eth0: set up with NAT and accessing the Internet

eth1: set up with "host-only networking", static IP, providing services to my MacOSX host

I was able to do this with a previous version of Ubuntu but I can't with this setup.

Could anybody recommend a step-by-step guide on how to do this, please?

UPDATE: This was due to DECnet changing the MAC address of all interfaces to "aa:00:04:00:0a:08". :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Mac host to connect to the Ubuntu guest OS, try changing the network adapter settings on the Ubuntu guest OS to ***Bridged Adapter***.